# Alternative to python/pandas iterrows solution

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a more efficient solution to an iterrows solution that i have been using on a fairly large data set. I am using this solution to check for the differences between two columns and then output the difference to the correct category of product.

I have a df that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['Oct-2019', 'Oranges + Grapes + Pears', 'Grapes + Pears'],
       ['Nov-2019', 'Oranges + Grapes + Pears', 'Oranges + Grapes + Pears']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Date', 'Previous shopping list', 'Recent shopping list'])
print(df)

Fish = ['Salmon', 'Trout']
Fruit = ['Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Pears']

     Date     PSL                 RSL
0  Oct-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Grapes + Pears
              + Pears + Salmon                     

1  Nov-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Oranges + Grapes
              + Pears + Trout     + Pears
```

Of which the expected outcome should be:

```
     Date     PSL                 RSL               Fruit lost   Fish Lost
0  Oct-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Grapes + Pears    Oranges      Salmon
              + Pears + Salmon                     

1  Nov-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Oranges + Grapes               Trout
              + Pears + Trout     + Pears
```

The solution I have works fine, but is just terribly slow. I was wondering if you guys have any better ways of getting the expected outcome that I am looking for.

My current way for finding the difference between the PSL and RSL column is:

```
def compare_items(x):
    return set(x.PSL) - set(x.RSL)

df['Products_lost'] = df.apply(compare_items, axis=1)
```

This gives me an output that looks like this:

```
           Date     PSL                 RSL                Products_lost
    0  Oct-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Grapes + Pears     {Oranges, Salmon}
                  + Pears + Salmon                     

    1  Nov-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Oranges + Grapes   {Trout}
                  + Pears + Trout     + Pears
```

I then use the following iterrows solution to check against the product category lists i have defined above, but it is really slow:

```
#checking fruits
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in Fruit: 
        if c in row['Products_lost']:
            df.ix[idx, 'Fruit_lost'] = c

#checking fish
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for c in Fish: 
        if c in row['Products_lost']:
            df.ix[idx, 'Fish_lost'] = c
```

All of this gives a final df that looks like this:

```
      Date     PSL                 RSL             Products_lost          Fruit lost   Fish Lost
0  Oct-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Grapes + Pears   {Oranges, Salmon}      Oranges      Salmon
              + Pears + Salmon                     

1  Nov-2019   Oranges + Grapes    Oranges + Grapes  {Trout}                            Trout
              + Pears + Trout     + Pears
```

I've been trying to use str.findall as a faster and quicker alternative to check through the 'Products_lost' category, but I keep getting errors. So far I have tried the following.

```
df['Fruit_lost']= df.Products_lost.str.findall('|'.join(Fruit)).apply(','.join)
df['Fruit_lost']= df.Products_lost.str.findall('|'.join(Fruit))
df['Fruit_lost']= df.Products_lost.apply(lambda x: x if x in Fruit else '')
```

I get errors with both the findall solutions and the lambda one works if there is only one element in the 'Products_lost' column.

I think my problem has to do with the elements in the 'Product_lost' column being a set, I have tried to convert using the code below to remove the '{}' but it does not seem to to help.

```
df['Products_lost'] = df.apply(compare_items, axis=1).apply(','.join)
```

I think the most important thing for me is that the output comes out clean, so no '[]' or '{}' brackets around the elements that appear in the 'Fruit_lost' or 'Fish_lost' columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use list comprehension and compare with `set.symmetric_difference`:

```
df["Fruit Lost"] = [set(x).symmetric_difference(set(y))
                    for x,y in zip(df["PSL"].str.findall("|".join(Fruit)),
                                   df["RSL"].str.findall("|".join(Fruit)))]
```

If you have `nan` in your columns, use `fillna` first:

```
df["Fruit Lost"] = [set(x).symmetric_difference(set(y))
                    for x,y in zip(df["PSL"].fillna("").str.findall("|".join(Fruit)),
                                   df["RSL"].fillna("").str.findall("|".join(Fruit)))]

print (df)

       Date                       PSL                       RSL Fruit Lost
0  Oct-2019  Oranges + Grapes + Pears            Grapes + Pears  {Oranges}
1  Nov-2019  Oranges + Grapes + Pears  Oranges + Grapes + Pears         {}
```

Comment: I get the type error: 'float' object is not iterable. Thank you for the suggestion! =)

Comment: You have nan in your `PSL` or `RSL` column?

Comment: 0 blanks on both columns in my dateset, but still have the same error.

Comment: Yep still the same issue! =(

Comment: Hmmm i'm almost certain there are missing values. Does `df["PSL"].isnull().sum()` and `df["RSL"].isnull().sum()` gives a number higher than 0?

Comment: got it working! Was my own type error, apologies for the barrage of questions! I was wondering, how can i remove the set brackets '{}' from the output?

Comment: You can use [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html).

Comment: I've been trying to do the following but i just cant get it to work =(

df["Fruit Lost"] = [set(x).symmetric_difference(set(y))
                    for x,y in zip(df["PSL"].fillna("").str.findall("|".join(Fruit)).apply(','.join),
                                   df["RSL"].fillna("").str.findall("|".join(Fruit)).apply(','.join))]

Any suggestion on where I am going wrong? Really appreciate your help, its the last thing I need to do! =)

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it!